# CKEditor 3.0 Height

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a way to set the height of CKEditor 3.0 to a percentage, such as 100%, such that it takes up the whole window?

I am currently using absolute values, but they do not blend well with my UI :(

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',{
    height: '600px'
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling with this resizing stuff on ckeditor 4 I made up this which works perfectly perfectly for me:

in config.js:

```
// prevent flashing of resizing by setting the content panel to zero height before it is resized
config.height = '0px';
config.width = '100%';
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // resize the editor(s) while the instance is ready
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() { 
        var textEditHeight      = $(".textPanel").height();
        var ckTopHeight         = $("#cke_1_top").height();
        var ckContentsHeight    = $("#cke_1_contents").height();

        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            $("#cke_"+i+"_contents").height( (textEditHeight - ckTopHeight - 10) + "px");

        }
    });

    // resize the editor(s) while resizing the browser
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var textEditHeight      = $(".textPanel").height();
        var ckTopHeight         = $("#cke_1_top").height();
        var ckContentsHeight    = $("#cke_1_contents").height();

        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            $("#cke_"+i+"_contents").height( (textEditHeight - ckTopHeight - 10) + "px");
        }
    });

});
```

I have multiple instances of the editor of the exact same size in tabs, for every language one, hence the for loop. If you have one editor you can leave that line away and use the standard id cke_1_contents.

In this example the heights are taken from the first editors toolbar (cke_1_top) and contentpanel (cke_1_contents). The .textPanel height is the surrounding div were the editor should fit in. I added 10px because I needed that for my layout.

I think it can be a littlebit more efficiënt (it initiates the resizing as many times as there are editors) but for now it is finally working flawlessly in all my recent browsers (ff, ie, chrome and safari).

Answer (score 11):

First add a function for resizing your edtior:

```
function resizeEditor() {

  var defaultHeight = 300;
  var newHeight = window.innerHeight-150; 
  var height = defaultHeight > newHeight ? defaultHeight: newHeight;

  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.resize('100%',height);
}
```

Note: 150  works for me, maybe change the value from 150 to more or less.

Call this from the window onresize Event:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  resizeEditor();
}
```

and add the first call to the constructor of your editor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
  {  
    on:
    {
      instanceReady: function(ev)
      {
        setTimeout(resizeEditor, 500);
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

I managed to configure a 100% height via CSS:

1. Configure the editor with `config.height = '100%'`, even when the docs say this isn't supported.
2. Put this in your CSS:

```css
span.cke_wrapper cke_ltr,table.cke_editor, td.cke_contents, span.cke_skin_kama, span.cke_wrapper, span.cke_browser_webkit{
    height: 100%!important;
}
```

I tested this with Chrome, Firefox and Safari and it worked fine. Since this is pure CSS, the height will get adjusted automatically when the window or the corresponding container is resized.

Comment: Try to use full screen mode. As you can see this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on ckeditor for CKEDITOR.config.height say that they do not support percentage units e.g.: 30%;
however, there is a td with a class of cke_contents. if you set the height on that (with an absolute value it will work).

It seems that ckeditor does not have a good solution for this problem.
The only other way I can think of is to use javascript to change the style on the above td.

Comment: Everything else you need to know about this problem is here http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.height

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked fine for me in order to set the height either with percentage or without it. Percentages are still not supported at all unless you hack it with one of the above solutions.

As stated in the documentation, you may set the height and css style with:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.config.height = 1000;
        CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/css/yourstyle.css';
    </script>
</head>
```

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.height

Answer (score 2):

Put this property in your css config file:

```
.cke_reset{
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a clean way to get the CKEditor window to be the same height as the textarea it is replacing. I'm using Drupal, and this is how I did it ...

In my theme I load up a javascript file, (using "scripts[] = default.js" in my .info file).

In this file I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Set CKEditor height
    if (typeof CKEDITOR!='undefined') {
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( e ) {
            e.editor.element.show();
            var elHeight = $(e.editor.element.$).height();
            e.editor.element.hide();
            e.editor.resize('100%', elHeight, true);
        });
    }
}
```

The beauty of this is you can then change the height using css.

I had been changing the settings.height via the wysiwyg module in wysiwyg/editors/js/ckeditor-3.0.js

```
Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.attach.ckeditor = function(context, params, settings) {
    // Apply editor instance settings.
    CKEDITOR.config.customConfig = '';

    // Match the height of the replaced field
    settings.height = $('#' + params.field).height();
}
```

but this would get overwritten during updates, so went with the top solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is the dojo version of the code above... in case anyone is interested...

```
var adjustEditor = function() {
  var editorNode = dom.byId('cke_messageEditor');
  console.log("editor node %s ", editorNode);
  var editorStyle = domStyle.getComputedStyle(editorNode);
  console.log("editor node %s and style %s", editorNode, editorStyle);
  var textEditHeight      = domGeom.getMarginBox(editorNode, editorStyle).h;

  var toolbarNode = dom.byId('cke_1_top');
  var toolbarStyle = domStyle.getComputedStyle(toolbarNode)
  var ckTopHeight = domGeom.getMarginBox(toolbarNode, toolbarStyle).h;

  var contentNode = dom.byId('cke_1_contents');
  var contentStyle = domStyle.getComputedStyle(contentNode)
  var ckContentsBox    = domGeom.getMarginBox(contentNode, contentStyle);
  console.log("text editor: %s, button bar: %s", textEditHeight, ckTopHeight);

  console.log("setting margin box to: %s ", JSON.stringify(ckContentsBox));
  ckContentsBox.h = textEditHeight - ckTopHeight;
  console.log("setting margin box to: %s ", JSON.stringify(ckContentsBox));

  domGeom.setMarginBox(contentNode, ckContentsBox, contentStyle);
}

// adjust editor immediately
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', adjustEditor);
// and again everytime the window is resized
on(window, "resize", adjustEditor);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got around doing this in CKEditor4, not sure if it is any use to you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <!-- tested with CKEditor 4.5.3 (revision 6c70c82) -->
  <style type="text/css">
   .cke_1 {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: static;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
   }
   .cke_inner {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    display: table !important;
   }   
   .cke_top { display: table-cell !important; }
   .cke_contents { height: 100% !important; display: table-row !important; }
   .cke_bottom { display: table-cell !important; }
   textarea.cktextarea {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
   }
  </style>
  <script>
   CKEDITOR.config.width = '100%';
   CKEDITOR.config.height = '100%';
   CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['maximize'] = {
    init: function(editor) {
     var command = editor.addCommand('maximize', {
      modes: { wysiwyg:1, source:1 },
      exec: function(editor) {
       if (editor.container.getStyle('position') != 'fixed') {
        this.setState(CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON);
        editor.container.setStyle('position', 'fixed');;
       } else {
        this.setState(CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF);
        editor.container.setStyle('position', 'static');
       }
      }
     });
     editor.ui.addButton('Maximize', { label: 'Maximize', command: 'maximize', toolbar: 'tools' });
    }
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="background: darkgray; padding: 0.5em; display: inline-block; position: fixed; left: 20px; top: 20px; left: 20px; right: 20px; bottom: 20px;">
   <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" class="cktextarea"></textarea>
   <script>CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');</script>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are not using the maximize plugin a lot of the javascript is unnecessary, I replaced the functionality of this plugin because it was breaking the new CSS (and breaking by itself after I set all the CSS !important).

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for me, without jQuery, working in C# WebBrowser control, also no vertical scroll when horizontal shown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2003-2017, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
-->
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>CKEditor Sample</title>
 <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script src="js/sample.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/samples.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="toolbarconfigurator/lib/codemirror/neo.css">
</head>
<body id="main">
 <div id="editor">
 </div>
 <script>
  initSample();

  CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function () { initFullSize(); });

  function initFullSize() {
   window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);

   document.getElementById("main").style.minWidth = "970px";
   document.getElementById("cke_1_resizer").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementsByClassName("cke_inner cke_reset")[0].style.height = "100%";

   onWindowResize();
  }

  function onWindowResize() {
   document.getElementById("main").style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight + "px";
   document.getElementById("cke_editor").style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 3 + "px";
   document.getElementById("cke_1_contents").style.height = (document.documentElement.clientHeight - document.getElementById("cke_1_top").clientHeight - document.getElementById("cke_1_bottom").clientHeight - 3) + "px";
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```